# Offline Version is fine, online is broken..

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, cloudflare

So recently I have been working on this website in my brackets environment no issue, after putting the finishing touches I decided to launch it well, Once I launched it my contact form completely broke.

This is what is looks like in Brackets (Local Environment) 
[image]

This is what the live version looks like.. 
[image]

As you can see we have some issue somewhere causing this.. I am just as a lost as to what..

To make life easier I made the code public in a repo : https://github.com/XMPPin/XMPP-Website

Index.html https://github.com/XMPPin/XMPP-Website/blob/master/index.html

Stylesheet.css https://github.com/XMPPin/XMPP-Website/blob/master/css/stylesheet.css

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It works fine on my end...

Comment: Same here. Baker, try to create fiddle of some sort with your code, don't force us to clone your repository just to test it. What browser in what version do you use to test it? Did you encounter this issue on other browsers?

Comment: @biphobe, I do apologize I always forget JSFiddle exists, so I used FireFox, Opera, Google Chrome and all of it responded the same way. I am thinking it might be an issue with Cloudflare tbh as I use Cloudflare on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So want to say thank you for the two who responded, I figured out it was an issue with CloudFlare cacheing the files incorrectly!

Comment: Sorry for such late response. I'm glad that you've solved your issue - you could pick your own answer as the correct one and close the question.